# org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.PageExpiredException--On closing of modal window(window.close(target)) in apache wicket

Tags: java, wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-1.6

Below is the page that in rendering and the attached child  page also:

Main Page:
LogLevelSettingManagement.java:

```
public class LogLevelSettingManagement extends BasePage {



    public LogLevelSettingManagement(PageParameters pageParameters) {
        super(pageParameters);
        getPage().get("body:dynamicLoglevel").add(new AttributeAppender("class", new Model<String>("active"), ""));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    protected void prepareForm(PageParameters pageParameters) {
        getUserRoleScreenMap();
        final Form<?> form = new Form("frmLoglevelMgmt");
        final FeedbackPanel feedbackDiv = new FeedbackPanel("logLevelMgmtFeedbackPanel");
        form.add(feedbackDiv.setOutputMarkupId(true));

        AjaxLink addLink = (new AjaxLink("addRecord") {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1219443392630482798L;

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                action = "add";
                modalWindow.show(target);
            }

        });
        logLevelList1 = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            logLevelList1 = UserAuthenticationDAO.getInstance().getObjects("getAllConfLogLevel");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.info(e.getMessage());

            logger.error("Exception while getting all logLevel data from ULF_LOG4J_LOG_LEVEL table", e);
        }
        ListView groupView = new ListView("lstColumnList", logLevelList1) {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -6841473204531956216L;

            @Override
            protected void populateItem(final ListItem pItem) {
                logLevelConfigureModel = (LogLevelConfigureModel) pItem.getModelObject();
                pItem.add(
                        new Label("lbllogLevelPackage", new PropertyModel(logLevelConfigureModel, "logLevelPackage")));
                pItem.add(new Label("lbllogLevelName", new PropertyModel(logLevelConfigureModel, "logLevelName")));

                AjaxLink editLink = new AjaxLink("lblEdit", pItem.getModel()) {

                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                        action = "edit";
                        logLevelConfigureModel = (LogLevelConfigureModel) getModelObject();
                        modalWindow.show(target);
                    }
                };
                editLink.setVisible(true);
                editLink.setOutputMarkupId(true);
                editLink.add(new Label("edit", new PropertyModel(logLevelConfigureModel, "lnkEdit")));
                pItem.add(editLink);

                if (null != webRollModel && (!webRollModel.isEdit_flg())) {
                    editLink.setEnabled(false);
                }

            }
        };

        modalWindow = new ModalWindow("modalWin");
        modalWindow.setTitle("Log Level Creation");
        modalWindow.setInitialHeight(520);
        modalWindow.setInitialWidth(712);
        modalWindow.setCookieName("modalWin-1");
        modalWindow.setPageCreator(new ModalWindow.PageCreator() {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -1127666594464759244L;

            @Override
            public Page createPage() {
                return new LogLevelCreation(LogLevelSettingManagement.this, modalWindow, action,
                        logLevelConfigureModel.copy()) {
                    /**
                     * 
                     */
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7425390418605058958L;

                    @Override
                    void setAction(String value) {

                        action = value;
                    }

                };

            }
        });
        modalWindow.setWindowClosedCallback(new ModalWindow.WindowClosedCallback() {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 5886472905133621681L;

            @Override
            public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                setResponsePage(LogLevelSettingManagement.class);
            }

        });

        wmc.add(modalWindow);
        AjaxLink applySettings = (new AjaxLink("saveSettings") {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                getAllLogLevelData();
                getSession().cleanupFeedbackMessages();
                getSession().info("Log levels are updated successfully");
                getSession().cleanupFeedbackMessages();
                form.add(feedbackDiv);
                setDataTableRefreshRequired(true);
                target.add(form);
            }
        });
        form.add(addLink);
        form.add(applySettings);
        form.add(groupView);
        wmc.add(modalWindow);
        wmc.add(form);

    }
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <wicket:head><title>Log Server - Log Level Settings Management</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/help.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        </wicket:head>
    </head>
<body>
<wicket:extend>
    <div>
        <div class="wideCap wideCap_wide">
            <form wicket:id="frmLoglevelMgmt">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="h1holder">
                        <h2>
                            Configure Log Level

                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="repeat">
                    <ul class="feedback" id="feedback"
                        wicket:id="logLevelMgmtFeedbackPanel">
                    </ul>

                    <!-- <table wicket:id="datatable" class="dataview" id="idd"
                        cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table> -->
                                <div>
                    <table border="0" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 width="100%"
                        style="table-layout: fixed;">
                        <tr width="90%">
                            <th width="15%">log Level Package</th>
                            <th width="15%">Log Level</th>
                            <th width="10%">Edit</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr wicket:id="lstColumnList" width="90%">
                            <td style="padding-left: 10px;" class="wrapword"><span wicket:id="lbllogLevelPackage"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left: 10px;" class="wrapword"><span
                                wicket:id="lbllogLevelName"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left: 10px;" ><a wicket:id="lblEdit"><span
                                    wicket:id="edit"></span> </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>  

                    <table align="center">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;">
                                <span class="btn_or_span"><input type="submit" value="Apply above settings"
                                    wicket:id="saveSettings" id="saveSettings" class="btn_or_sbt" /></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div wicket:id="modalWin"></div>
    </div>
</wicket:extend>
</body>
</html>
```

And the page on modal window :

LoglevelCreation.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Log Level Creation</title>
</head>
<body wicket:id="body" onload="">
        <div id="flyout-mask"></div>
    <div id="bysy_indicator"
                style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -50px; margin-left: -50px; width: 50px; height: 50px;">
                <img id="busyImg" wicket:id="flyoutImg" width="50" height="50" />
            </div>

            <span class="Title">Log Level Creation</span> <br /> <br />

    <form wicket:id="form" style="border: none;">


                        <div class="feedback" wicket:id="logLevelCreationFeedbackPanel"></div>

            <table align="left">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;">Log Level Package</td>
                    <td><input type="text" wicket:id="loglevelPackage" class="mandatoryFlag" size="35"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-left: 10px;">Log Level</td>
                    <td><select wicket:id="logLevelName" class="mandatoryFlag" >
                            <option>--Select Log Level--</option>
                    </select></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <table width="80%" class="repeat" align="center">
                <tr style="height: 35px; text-align: top">
                    <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="4">
                        <span class="btn_or_span"><input type="submit" value="Save"
                            wicket:id="saveEditAdd" id="saveEditAdd" class="submit" /></span> <span
                        class="btn_or_span"><input type="submit" value="Cancel"
                            wicket:id="cancel" id="cancel" class="submit" /></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>




    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the java class for Loglevel Creation.html:

```
public abstract class LogLevelCreation extends WebPage implements IHeaderContributor{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1466788110179772918L;
    private static final String FEEDBACK_DIV = "logLevelCreationFeedbackPanel";
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LogLevelCreation.class);
    private static ResourceReference pkgResourcereference = new ResourceReference(BasePage.class, "./loading.gif") {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public IResource getResource() {
            return new ResourceStreamResource(new FileResourceStream(new File("./loading.gif")));
        }
    };
    private Genericdao dao = null;
    DataTable<IModel> table = null;
    protected Form form = null;
    boolean isDataTableRefreshRequired = false;
    private WebMarkupContainer wmc;
    private String logLeveL;
    private TextField<String> logLevelPackage;
    private DropDownChoice<String> logLevelName;
    AjaxButton submit;
    protected ModalWindow componentWindow = new ModalWindow("componentWindow");
    private ModalWindow window;
    private Image loading;


    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public LogLevelCreation(LogLevelSettingManagement loglevelsettingManagement, ModalWindow window, String action,
             LogLevelConfigureModel loglevelModel) {
        form = new Form("form");
        getSession().cleanupFeedbackMessages();
        if(loglevelModel!=null && loglevelModel.getLogLevelName()!=null){
            logLeveL = (loglevelModel.getLogLevelName().isEmpty() ? null : loglevelModel.getLogLevelName());
        }

        dao = Genericdao.getInstance();
        this.window=window;
        prepareForm(action, loglevelModel);

    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void prepareForm(final String action,final  LogLevelConfigureModel loglevelModel) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        wmc = new WebMarkupContainer("body");
        wmc.add(new AbstractBehavior() {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = -8516603914734934172L;

            @Override
            public void bind(Component component) {
                component.add(new AttributeAppender("onload", new Model<String>("setupFunc();"), ""));
                super.bind(component);
            }
        });
        final FeedbackPanel feedbackDiv = new FeedbackPanel(FEEDBACK_DIV);
        form.add(feedbackDiv.setOutputMarkupId(true));
        logLevelPackage = new TextField<String>("loglevelPackage", new PropertyModel<String>(loglevelModel, "logLevelPackage"));
        logLevelPackage.add(ValidationMsgBehaviour.VALIDATIONMSGBEHAV);
        logLevelPackage.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        List<String> logLevelList=new ArrayList<String>();
        logLevelList.add("DEBUG");
        logLevelList.add("INFO");
        logLevelList.add("WARN");
        logLevelList.add("ERROR");
        logLevelList.add("FATAL");
        logLevelName = new DropDownChoice<String>("logLevelName", new PropertyModel<String>(loglevelModel,
                "logLevelName"), logLevelList);
        logLevelName.add(ValidationMsgBehaviour.VALIDATIONMSGBEHAV);
        logLevelName.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        if (action.equals("edit")) {
            logger.info("Edit button click");
            logLevelPackage.setEnabled(false);
            logLevelPackage.setVisible(true);
            logLevelName.setEnabled(true);
            logLevelName.setVisible(true);
        }else {
            // TO:DO : Set visible fields 
        }
    submit = new AjaxButton("saveEditAdd", form) {

            /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1594616261153407739L;

            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> arg1) {
                logger.info("## inside submit button click");
                try {
                    if (loglevelModel != null) {
                        if(!validateFields()){
                            form.add(feedbackDiv);
                            feedbackDiv.setVisible(true);
                            target.add(form); 
                            return;
                        }
                        addLogLevel(target);


                    }
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    logger.error("Error while saving users data in database", e1);
                    getSession().cleanupFeedbackMessages();
                    getSession().info("Error occured while saving user's data.");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Error while saving Users Data", e);
                    getSession().cleanupFeedbackMessages();
                    getSession().info("Error occured while saving user's data.");
                }
            }

            private boolean addLogLevel(AjaxRequestTarget target) throws Exception {
                if(action.equals("add")){
                try {
                    dao.insertObject("logLevelData", loglevelModel);
                }catch (SQLException e) {
                    logger.info(e.getMessage());
                    logger.error("Error occurs  at plus symbol while adding new log in  datatable");
                }

                    // Insert Data
                    getSession().cleanupFeedbackMessages();
                    getSession().info("Log levels are added successfully");
                    getSession().cleanupFeedbackMessages();


                }else if (action.equals("edit")) {
                    // Update Existing Data
                    logger.info("Edit button click 2");
                    try {
                    dao.updateObject("logLevelData", loglevelModel);
                    }catch (SQLException e) {
                        logger.info(e.getMessage());
                        logger.error("Error occurs  the in updating  at popup edit button bootup datatable");
                    }

                    getSession().cleanupFeedbackMessages();
                    getSession().info("Log levels are edit/updated successfully");


                }


                window.close(target);
                return true;
            }

            private boolean validateFields() {

                if(loglevelModel.getLogLevelName() == null){
                    error("Log Level Name cannot be empty."); 
                    return false;
                }else if(loglevelModel.getLogLevelPackage() == null){
                    error("Log level package cannot be empty."); 
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
                target.add(form);   
                }
            };

            AjaxButton cancel = new AjaxButton("cancel", form) {

                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -7266817836385572901L;
                @Override
                protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {

                }
                @Override
                protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) { //unused
                    target.add(form);
                }
            };
            loading = new Image("flyoutImg", pkgResourcereference);
            loading.setMarkupId("busyImg");
            loading.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            loading.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

            form.add(logLevelPackage);
            form.add(logLevelName);
            form.add(submit);
            form.add(cancel);
            wmc.add(loading);
            wmc.add(form);
            wmc.add(componentWindow);
            wmc.add(new Label("versionNo", VersionInfo.getVersionNo()));
            add(wmc);


    }


    abstract void setAction(String string);

    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        String themeName = com.ecs.ulf.logserver.web.Application.getThemeName();
        themeName = "../" + themeName;
        response.renderString("<link href=\"" + themeName + "styles/standard.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />");
        response.renderString("<link href=\"" + themeName + "styles/modal.css\" type=\"text/css\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />");
        response.renderString("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"../scripts/flyout.js\"></script>");
        response.renderString("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"../scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js\"></script>");
    }

    }
```

Whenever I close the modal window on window.close(target).
LoglevelSettingManagement page is unable to redirect and I get an error :
 ERROR :Exception trace  [ org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.PageExpiredException ] Page with id '7' has expired.org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.PageExpiredException: Page with id '7' has expired.
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:169)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.getPage(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:100)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:165)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:750)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:252)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:209)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:280)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:162)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:218)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

and application is redirected to internal error page

Comment: Most of the cases when PageExpiredException is being thrown is because the page with that id has had a problem in the serialization in the previous request. Check the server logs for errors in the serialization/storing process.

Comment: How can I keep the instance of the parent page active @martin-g

Comment: And can I set setMaxSizePerSession or the particular page ? to resolve the issue ? #wicket

Comment: Wicket keeps only the last used page instance in the Http Session. All previously used page instances are stored on the disk, as byte[], i.e. serialized. The `MaxSizePerSession` is the maximum size on the disk Wicket can use for a Session, i.e. per user. It is not per page. As I said - make sure the parent page serializes without errors. Or use ModalWindow backed by a Panel, not by a Page. This way there won't be a parent page but it will be the same page instance.

Comment: Thanks for the solution .It Worked My parent page was not serializing properly @martin-g